# FileStream for sharing the file between different processes

Tags: c#, .net, file, filestream, sharing

I am using the following code to modify the XML file that can be used from multiple processes

```
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.ReadWrite, FileShare.Read))
{
    var d = XDocument.Load(fs);
    d.Descendants("TestNode").FirstOrDefault().Descendants("MyInfo").FirstOrDefault().Attribute("Id").Value = "Tested Successfully";
    XElement x1 = new XElement(new XElement("PoolId", "A91"));
    d.Root.Add(x1);
    fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
    d.Save(fs);
}
```

This method is inside the LOCK object.

Now, I always want to overwrite the content of the XML file so i've used

```
fs.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

is this right? Is there a better way?

Comment: What is the purpose of the lock?  If it's for mutual exclusion to work cross process, you'll need to use a mutex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save overwrites already, you don't need to call Seek.

What are you doing with the XElement?

```
new XElement(new XElement("PoolId", "A91"));
```

could just read

```
new XElement("PoolId", "A91");
```